# ehcaching in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

I am using ehcache for caching in Spring mvc. Consider the case where a controller to provide data a number of times through various methods to connect to the database If we use cache to cache all of the services have the same cache name or not?

example:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String mycontroller(){
      ...

     List1= Service.get(Id);
     Info = Service.getInfo(Id); 
     messages = Service.allMessage(Id);
     ...
```

}

and also if the server is reset, cached data will be lost?

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhcacheCacheManager"   p:cache-manager="ehcache"/>

 <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"  p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
```

and ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>
<cache name="contactCache" maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>
       <cache name="cachname"
       maxElementsInMemory="100"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
       diskPersistent="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

Comment: Are you using the Spring Cache abstraction with EhCache? http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: @Edward Smith yes i use. this exception occur when i run it: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhcacheCacheManager

Comment: You have misspelled EhcacheCacheManager in your XML configuration, it should be: `EhCacheCacheManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should use multiple cache names (and thus multiple caches), one or more per Service class.

Also, in most configurations of EhCache, your cached data will be lost upon application restart. However if you consult the [documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/operations/shutdown#the-shutdown-hook), you will find that you can have the cache become persistent across restarts, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using single cache for storing all services data because cache can store multiple entries of key-value types which serves one of the basic purpose of cache.

It is easy to maintain cache's in case only few number of services needs to be cached. But creating cache's if services are multiple is not preferrable.